# Get only response headers in em_http_request

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, em-http-request

How can I get only response headers in an em_http_request?

I tried to use this code:

```
EventMachine.run do
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('my_url').get
  http.headers do |headers|
    Fiber.current.resume headers
  end
end
```

but I don't want to receive the whole body. How I can stop the request's execution?
`http.close` doesn't work.

**UPD**
`http.instance_variable_get(:'@conn').close` helps me, but may be you know more interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the body, [you should do a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET`](https://ochronus.com/http-head-request-good-uses/). To terminate the event loop you need to explicitly call [`EventMachine.stop`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine/TickLoop#stop-instance_method).

```
EventMachine.run do
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('my_url').head
  http.headers do |headers|
    # do something with headers

    EventMachine.stop
  end
end
```

Comment: Not the event loop. Just request. See UPD

Comment: +1, yes, a HEAD request is the proper way to do this.

Comment: When you do a `HEAD` request, the request is over after the headers were received _by definition_. I suppose that by the time the `header` callback is called, the connection may already be closed. If you don't want to terminate the event loop, just remove the `EventMachine.stop`